# How to find PL/SQL program that Oracle Forms interface integrates

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have the following problem:

There is a Forms interface that is running error

> ORA-04068: existing state of packages ()has been discarded.

I need to find the PL/SQL program that is called by the Forms interface. Could someone tell me how to find it?

[image]

Comment: recompile the .fmb; it will show the exact place/s where error is/are. you can start your fix from there

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't have to be *fatal*. For example, if form uses a package into which a new procedure or function has been added, you just have to recompile the form and it'll work.

But, if you added a new parameter to a procedure which is called from the form, then you'll have to modify the form PL/SQL unit to reflect those changes (unless newly added parameters are added at the end of the parameters' list and are set to be NULL by default).

So:

- open the form in Forms Builder
- push combination of <Ctrl + Shift + K> to recompile (*All*) the form
- it'll automatically fetch changes of all stored PL/SQL programs

  - read: you don't really have to find out *which one* is to blame; doesn't matter
- create a .FMX file
- run the form
- if everything is OK (i.e. if description of stored procedures which are used in the form) didn't change, the form will work

  - otherwise, it'll fail, but it'll now tell you what caused the error so you'll be able to investigate it

---

To cut a long story short: recompile the form.

Comment: Could this error happen if the form is connected to the database while the packages were recompiled? If this form is called from another form and they never restarted the application, I believe the error would persist as well. I can test this at work tomorrow and find out.

Comment: As far as I can tell, @Zynon, yes - it could happen. On the other hand, if someone was using the package and developer tried to compile it, compilation would "hang" (i.e. wait until the package is "released"). But yes - I agree - test it and see what happens.